# RunTimeException LibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, firebase, exception, runtime, runtimeexception

Gradle

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.appmaster.akash.messageplus'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have no clue why i keep getting this error... i've searched a lot and the reason is mismatch of firebase libraries versions... but even when all the versions are same i get this error... please help... if you need more code please ask and it was working before i added that theartofdev library... but i dont think this error is because of that

Comment: what is the full error?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s

20 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 16 up-to-date

Comment: But i want to add that library

Comment: Its running... but i want to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.6+ version of Android Image Cropper was [built with Support Libs 27.x.x](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases).  Use version 2.5.1 for compatibility with 26.1.0

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
```

Also, you are including the legacy Firebase SDK:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

Do you really need that?  It's risky to use both the legacy and "new" SDK in the same project.  I don't know of any capabilities in the legacy SDK that are not also available in the new.  See the [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).